# IE 11 Selenium WebDriver Input Text is slow even with 32-bit IEDriverServer.exe

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, robotframework

I've had a problem regarding the slow pacing of the keyword `Input Text`. I've seen solutions online but so far it seems nothing seems to fit my needs. I've got a 32-bit `IEDriverServer.exe` and it is still slow. One thing I noticed is that when I remove the registry item `TabProcGrowth` with the value 0 in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main`, The speed will go back to normal which is fast but it won't detect any other window (opened through buttons) which is most of our tests. Bringing the registry item back will make the driver see other windows but will now be slow in inputting text which we have a lot. Any ideas on how to face this? We are using pure `Robot Framework` integrated with `selenium2library` Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the "TabProcGrowth".
U just need to;

1. Open Registry Editor in Administrative mode.
2. Look into HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet\Settings\Zones
3. Under keys 1-4, look for a value named 2500
4. Change the value data to “0”

Works fine to me. able to get control over new window in ie using robot framework.